# Comparing two date strings in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime

Let's say I have a string: "10/12/13" and "10/15/13", how can I convert them into date objects so that I can compare the dates? For example to see which date is before or after.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: [`dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil)

Comment: How the heck can you have a date `10/15/13`?

Comment: @aIKid October 15, 2013?

Comment: if this is all you need to do and these dates are always of this format, would it not be easier to compare them yourself?

Comment: @gongzhitaao ahaha. Missed that

Answer (score 65):

Use [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime as dt
>>> a = dt.strptime("10/12/13", "%m/%d/%y")
>>> b = dt.strptime("10/15/13", "%m/%d/%y")
>>> a > b
False
>>> a < b
True
>>>
```

Comment: for some reason %y (lower case y) gave me "Unconverted data remains " error, while %Y (upper case Y) worked. Why?

Comment: @Gnuey - The datetime format strings are case-sensitive.  `%Y` is not the same as `%y`.  `%Y` tells Python to match a 4-digit year such as `2014`.  `%y` however matches a 2-digit year such as `14` for the year `2014`.  You must be trying to match a 4-digit year with the 2-digit `%y` specifier.  Here is a reference on the available format specifiers: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: Ahh I see. Didn't catch that very valuable detail of "!4"vs"2014". Thank you for the answer and many thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 16):

If you like to use the [`dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) and its parser:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

date1 = parse('10/12/13')
date2 = parse('10/15/13')

print date1 - date2
print date2 > date2
```

Comment: pip install python-dateutil

Answer (score 14):

Here's one solution using [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
>>> date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('10/12/13', '%m/%d/%y')
>>> date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('10/15/13', '%m/%d/%y')
>>> date1 < date2
True
>>> date1 > date2
False
```

Comment: for some reason %y (lower case y) gave me "Unconverted data remains " error, while %Y (upper case Y) worked. Why?

Comment: `%y` works with year without centuries - as a zero padded number (01, 02, 03.. and so on). While `%Y`works with year with century (decimal) number: (1999, 1979). What's your data?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime).

```
from datetime import datetime

a = datetime.strptime('10/12/13', '%m/%d/%y')
b = datetime.strptime('10/15/13', '%m/%d/%y')

print 'a' if a > b else 'b' if b > a else 'tie'
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is 7 years old, but wanted to say that you can compare two date strings without converting them to dates

```
>>> "10/12/13" > "10/15/13"
False
>>> "10/12/13" < "10/15/13"
True
>>> "10/12/13" == "10/15/13"
False
```

If there is anything wrong with this approach I would love for someone to tell me.

Comment: Please refer to this answer for why this is a bad way to compare date strings. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31350422/4589310

Comment: A counterexample: `'10/15/13' > '10/12/14'` but `October 15, 2013` was before `October 12, 2014`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to accomplish this is using Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
d1=pd.to_datetime("10/12/13")
d2=pd.to_datetime("10/12/15")

d1>d2

>>False
```

Comment: Even though this is a valid way, it's not the simplest

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

d1="10/12/13"
d2="10/15/13"
date = d1.split('/')
d1=datetime.datetime(int(date[2]),int(date[1]),int(date[0])) 
date = d2.split('/')
d2=datetime.datetime(int(date[2]),int(date[1]),int(date[0]))
if d1 > d2 :
    ## Code
today = datetime.datetime.today()
if d1 > today :
    ## code
```

---

Comment: Please add more details to your answer, maybe a brief explanation of what the code does would help.