# Filter all rows in a DataFrame with a selected Month (Pandas Datetime)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, date, datetime

I have the following set of dates and I'm looking to filter all the rows if it has '2022-02' in it.

```
            Sunday      Monday      Tuesday     Wednesday   Thursday    Friday      Saturday
January     2021-12-26  2021-12-27  2021-12-28  2021-12-29  2021-12-30  2021-12-31  2022-01-01
January     2022-01-02  2022-01-03  2022-01-04  2022-01-05  2022-01-06  2022-01-07  2022-01-08
January     2022-01-09  2022-01-10  2022-01-11  2022-01-12  2022-01-13  2022-01-14  2022-01-15
January     2022-01-16  2022-01-17  2022-01-18  2022-01-19  2022-01-20  2022-01-21  2022-01-22
January     2022-01-23  2022-01-24  2022-01-25  2022-01-26  2022-01-27  2022-01-28  2022-01-29
February    2022-01-30  2022-01-31  2022-02-01  2022-02-02  2022-02-03  2022-02-04  2022-02-05
February    2022-02-06  2022-02-07  2022-02-08  2022-02-09  2022-02-10  2022-02-11  2022-02-12
February    2022-02-13  2022-02-14  2022-02-15  2022-02-16  2022-02-17  2022-02-18  2022-02-19
February    2022-02-20  2022-02-21  2022-02-22  2022-02-23  2022-02-24  2022-02-25  2022-02-26
March       2022-02-27  2022-02-28  2022-03-01  2022-03-02  2022-03-03  2022-03-04  2022-03-05
March       2022-03-06  2022-03-07  2022-03-08  2022-03-09  2022-03-10  2022-03-11  2022-03-12
March       2022-03-13  2022-03-14  2022-03-15  2022-03-16  2022-03-17  2022-03-18  2022-03-19
March       2022-03-20  2022-03-21  2022-03-22  2022-03-23  2022-03-24  2022-03-25  2022-03-26
April       2022-03-27  2022-03-28  2022-03-29  2022-03-30  2022-03-31  2022-04-01  2022-04-02
April       2022-04-03  2022-04-04  2022-04-05  2022-04-06  2022-04-07  2022-04-08  2022-04-09
....
```

I am trying to filter out the rows with '2022-02'. As shown below:
PS this DataFrame has a row of March because '2022-02' is also present in that row.

```
            Sunday      Monday      Tuesday     Wednesday   Thursday    Friday      Saturday
February    2022-01-30  2022-01-31  2022-02-01  2022-02-02  2022-02-03  2022-02-04  2022-02-05
February    2022-02-06  2022-02-07  2022-02-08  2022-02-09  2022-02-10  2022-02-11  2022-02-12
February    2022-02-13  2022-02-14  2022-02-15  2022-02-16  2022-02-17  2022-02-18  2022-02-19
February    2022-02-20  2022-02-21  2022-02-22  2022-02-23  2022-02-24  2022-02-25  2022-02-26
March       2022-02-27  2022-02-28  2022-03-01  2022-03-02  2022-03-03  2022-03-04  2022-03-05
```

I've tried these methods, without any success.

```
calendar.loc[(calendar >= '2022-02-01') & (calendar < '2020-03-01')]
```

```
calendar[calendar == '2022-02-01']
```

Comment: quick question, are your values strings or datetime objects, in the pandas dataframe? because your attempts indicate they are strings.

Comment: use `DataFrame.apply()` method and pass a lambda function that checks if the desired value is present in the dates

Comment: @AkshaySehgal yes they are strings

Comment: @Henul, i have added some additional notes for your reference on why some of the alternate methods being recommended here are a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments -

> yes they are strings

IIUC, these dates are strings, you are trying to treat them as a date variable while searching for strings). **The ideal way to solve this would be to convert everything to datetime** and then use `pd.series.dt.` methods but, since all your data is already strings and this is just a simple string search problem, feel free to just use the following.

1. `row.str.find('2022-02')>=0)` this checks if, in a given row, it finds the given string.
2. `calender.apply(lambda row ...` applies it to each row independently.
3. `.any(1)` takes an `OR` between the True/False values for each row, to give a True, if any of the rows contain `2022-02`
4. `calender[...]` using the above boolean series to get only those rows that you want.

Hope this explains the code below -

```
calender[calender.apply(lambda row: row.str.find('2022-02')>=0).any(1)]
```

```
              Sunday      Monday     Tuesday   Wednesday    Thursday  \
February  2022-01-30  2022-01-31  2022-02-01  2022-02-02  2022-02-03   
February  2022-02-06  2022-02-07  2022-02-08  2022-02-09  2022-02-10   
February  2022-02-13  2022-02-14  2022-02-15  2022-02-16  2022-02-17   
February  2022-02-20  2022-02-21  2022-02-22  2022-02-23  2022-02-24   
March     2022-02-27  2022-02-28  2022-03-01  2022-03-02  2022-03-03   

              Friday    Saturday  
February  2022-02-04  2022-02-05  
February  2022-02-11  2022-02-12  
February  2022-02-18  2022-02-19  
February  2022-02-25  2022-02-26  
March     2022-03-04  2022-03-05
```

---

#### Avoid comparing date strings as `2022-01-10 > 2022-02-11`

Just to add here, for posterity, comparing dates as strings using `>` or `<=` is not a good practice, and its discussed in detail on this popular SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350373/comparing-date-strings-in-python/31350422#31350422).

Furthermore, doing string comparisons only compares Unicode values for each character, and is prone to failed cases such as this `'10/15/13' > '10/12/14'`

So I would highly recommend avoiding these types of coding practices.

Comment: Are you aware why it's showing this?   /var/folders/6p/6nhcvd0n34g57_w2y5xrt4th0000gn/T/ipykernel_7583/2755825265.py:1: FutureWarning: In a future version of pandas all arguments of DataFrame.any and Series.any will be keyword-only.
  calendar[calendar.apply(lambda row: row.str.find('2022-02')>=0).any(1)]

Comment: First you can use from map method instead of apply. map is very faster than apply. Also using from lambda functions in map and apply method is unefficient. This is a bad idea

Comment: Glad to help. the warning is due to the indexing, nothing to worry about. you can use  loc to do the indexing which should not throw this warning, if i am not mistaken

Comment: @Alireza, can you please share your source? I dont believe that is correct.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal Could you please advice where should I replace "loc" with?

Comment: No, this code should work fine. This should not be an issue. feel free to ignore that warning. but do google around it to just know why that is occuring. you will find some excellent answers on SO already that discuss this in detail.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal map method is for series and apply use for dataframe. Series method are faster than from dataframe methods in pandas. Also you can check it on large dataset with timeit

Comment: right but he wants to apply it to the dataframe not a every column independently

Comment: @AkshaySehgalhe want to find rows with this condition and it doesnt need to usr from apply and check it for all columns

Answer (score 0):

Use from this code

```py
df[(df.Saturday <= '2022-03-06')&(df.Sunday >= '2022-01-26')]
```

it is very simple and fast
If your dataset is large before this line you can use from convert_dtypes method(some times pandas use from object for data type and it is very slow)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm looking to filter the dates from all the rows, and not just Saturday.

Comment: @Alireza, that might not work because the values in the table are string values. you cant compare them with `>` or `<=`

Comment: @Henul if your saturday and sunday is between 2 dates that i write, then you have a date in 2022-02 in at least 1 column in the row. Filtering is very faster than applying methods

Comment: @AkshaySehgal no it is wrong. Pandas can compare strings. You can test it

Comment: the string comparisons in python are only comparing characters one by one based on their Unicode values, which might not have the intended behavior that OP wants.

Comment: Just because your code runs, doesnt mean it is right :).

Comment: @AkshaySehgal it is a simple problem that if a date is before than another dates, the string of them keeps the order of them. If you can not understand it, you can read more about functions and their operations. I can not discuss about low level problems
Gooooood luck

Comment: There is no need to be rude here, and thanks for wishing me luck. with you the same :). Just to add this for everyones reference - here is a counter example `'10/15/13' > '10/12/14'` and here is the thread discussing why your solution is a bad idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350373/comparing-date-strings-in-python/31350422#31350422