# Compare two datetime stringspython

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I need to compare two dates given below:

```
my_date = 'Mar 15 00:00:00 2019'
date_to_check = "Sep 17 04:00:05 2018"

if my_date<=date_to_check:
     print(True)
```

It should not print anything. But it is printing 'True'. I figured out the problem- It is comparing only Mar 15 to Sep 17, not taking year into consideration.
And I cannot change date format to some other because I need to compare the dates in the text file.

Any comments on this.

Comment: In the question, I see a code snippet comparing strings *not dates*, and `date_to_check` is lexicographically larger than `my_date`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806911/string-comparison-technique-used-by-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing two date strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365854/comparing-two-date-strings-in-python)

Comment: @vahdet, yeah I saw that date_to_check is lexicographically larger than my_date,. Is there any way to compare these two date strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

my_date = 'Mar 15 00:00:00 2019'
date_to_check = "Sep 17 04:00:05 2018"

my_date_object = datetime.strptime(my_date, '%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
date_to_check_object = datetime.strptime(date_to_check, '%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')

if my_date_object <= date_to_check_object:
    print(True)
```