# How to compare string time in python

Tags: python, string, datetime

I have two string inputs and I need to compare if their difference is 15 min

input1: 20-25-43 (string, represent HH-MM-SS)
input2: 20-40-43(string, represent HH-MM-SS)

Initially, I was thinking to replace hyphen(-) and convert string to number and `input2 - input1`. However, the result is either 1500 or 5500.

I am wondering if there is possible to use the time() method of DateTime objects?

Comment: What does this have to do with `bucket` or `amazon-s3`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing two date strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365854/comparing-two-date-strings-in-python)

Comment: You could use the base package time methods to do this, but it's probably overkill. Converting string to numbers and subtracting is fine, but remember there are 60 seconds per minute and 60 minutes per hour.

Comment: @ScottHunter it is s3 key, key naming convention including id-date1-time1-date2-time2.extension

Comment: @alift Yes, it does!! thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

You can use [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) to parse them.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> s1 = datetime.strptime('20-25-43','%H-%M-%S')
>>> s2 = datetime.strptime('20-40-43','%H-%M-%S')
>>> (s2-s1).seconds
900
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `datetime.strptime` you can calculate differences between times. Since you're using a `string` you need to use `strptime` to convert it into a `datetime` object.

```
string1 = '20-25-43'
string2 = '20-40-42'
FRMAT = '%H-%M-%S'

str(datetime.strptime(string2, FRMAT) - datetime.strptime(string1, FRMAT))


#'0:15:00'
```

You can then check that your result is `==` to 15 minutes.