# How to compare two dates: one from file modification date, other from sql table in Python?

Tags: python

I need to compare the modification date of a file with a date that comes from a table, but the method I'm using is not the best, can you help?

Right now I'm doing this:

```
modificationTime = time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y', time.localtime(os.path.getmtime(file))) 

max_load_date = (engine.execute("SELECT MAX(load_date) from %s where filename = '%s'" % (table, os.path.basename(file)))).first()[0]

print(max_load_date < modificationTime)
```

it's flawless because 23/05/2022 is bigger than 22/05/2022, but if 23/05/2022 it's smaller than 24/04/2022.

I've tried to convert the date coming from the database, but failed...

I've tried something like this

```
time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y', max_load_date)
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365854/comparing-two-date-strings-in-python

Comment: you should compare datetime objects instead of strings